# gitlab-ci: exclude merge requests from specific branch

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I would like gitlab-ci to ignore merge from a specific branch.

Example: I have 3 branches. **master**, **development** & **test**.

If I push the code directly or merge the code from any branch to master/development, the pipelines get executed.

Now, I don't want pipeline to get running when I merge from **test** branch specifically.

I would like to exclude merge from **test** branch to **development** or **master**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by specifying an [if-rule](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#rulesif) for the jobs you want to exclude.
For example:

```
docker build:
  script: docker build -t my-image:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG .
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME != "test" || ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "test" and ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME != "master" || $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME != "development"))'
```

The 2 variables `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` and `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME` are [automatically defined](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) only in the case of a merge request.

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab CI does not have to verify "what" is being merged, only "where" it is being merged.

You could do it using script which uses `git` commands (it allows to check both parents for merge commit). However, I advise you to do not do it. The reason is you can miss build for changes merged from not "test" branch.

E.g.

1. dev merges feature branch to master
2. Gitlab CI starts build as it is not "test" branch
3. while build is running, dev merges "test" to master
4. Gitlab CI will cancel previous pipeline and start new one
5. Script will detect merge happened from "test" and exit

At this point, build started at p2 is cancelled by Gitlab, build started at p2 is cancelled by your script. As a result, required build is missing.